# mq_receive - Connection timed out

Tags: c, linux, queue, posix

I'm using mq_receive function and somehow I'm randomly getting Connection timed out error (ETIMEOUT), how is it possible with this function, as it takes no timeout parameter?

Here's my routine
There is only one queue, lets call it Q:

1. servers opens Q queue with params: O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK
2. servers starts polling on Q fd
3. clients sends data to Q queue (params: O_WRONLY)
4. servers gets an event on the descriptor
5. server tries to read from Q - and here I get Connection time out, and this is random.

How is that possible?

Here are the additional queue params that server passes to mq_open

```
struct mq_attr attr = {.mq_curmsgs = 0,
                   .mq_flags   = 0,
                   .mq_maxmsg  = 10,
                   .mq_msgsize = sizeof(struct ipc_response)};
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post [representative] code: `server.c` and `client.c` We want an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we would like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].